# genereate unique row index in a 2D tensor as an output 1D tensor with PyTorch

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, tensor, torch

When I implement `target` in in-batch multi-class classification on PyTorch (version 1.6), I have the following problem.

I got a variable `D` <class 'torch.Tensor'> （related to label description) of size as torch.Size([16, 128]), i.e. [data_size,token_id_size].

The original idea was to generate a `target` tensor of torch.Size([16]), each value is unique, corresponding to the rows in `D`, from 0 to 16 as `[0,1,2,...,15]`, for in-batch multi-class classification.

This can be done using `target = torch.LongTensor(torch.arange(16))`

But there maybe repeated, non-unique rows in `D`, so I would like that the same, unique row in `D` has the its unique index in `target`. For example `D` has row0, row1, row8 the same token_ids or vector and the other rows are all different from each other, then target should be `[0,0,2,3,4,5,6,0,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]` or `[0,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]`, wher the former has still indexes 0-15 (but no 1 and 7) and the latter has indexes of all in 0-13.

How can I implement this?

Comment: I did not get what the network is all about, but if you are looking for a unique 16 length array with values from 0-15, then can you use randInt to populate the array?

Comment: The target is dependent on the rows of D (which is the source to create the target vector, in my case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See answers of the simplified question (i) [generate 1D tensor as unique index of rows of an 2D tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72529669/generate-1d-tensor-as-unique-index-of-rows-of-an-2d-tensor) and (ii) [generate 1D tensor as unique index of rows of an 2D tensor (keeping the order and the original index)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72689843/generate-1d-tensor-as-unique-index-of-rows-of-an-2d-tensor-keeping-the-order-an), which address the problem of this question.

But these seem not useful to improve the contrastive multi-class classification.