# generate 1D tensor as unique index of rows of an 2D tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

Let's say we transform a 2D tensor to a 1D tensor by giving each, different row a different index, from `0` to `the number of rows - 1`.

```
[[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]] -> [0,1,2]
```

But if there are same rows, then we repeate the index, like this below.

```
[[1,2],[1,2],[1,4]] -> [0,0,2]

[[1,2],[1,3],[1,2]] -> [0,1,0]
```

How to implement this on PyTorch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do so using [`torch.Tensor.unique`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unique.html) and returning the inverse which provides the indices out of the box:

```
>>> _, i = x.unique(dim=0, return_inverse=True)

>>> i # first example
tensor([0, 1, 2])
```