# generate 1D tensor as unique index of rows of an 2D tensor (keeping the order and the original index)

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, torch

This question is an updated version of [generate 1D tensor as unique index of rows of an 2D tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72529669/generate-1d-tensor-as-unique-index-of-rows-of-an-2d-tensor)

Let's say we transform a 2D tensor to a 1D tensor by giving each, different row a different index, from `0` to `the number of rows - 1`.

```
[[1,4],[1,3],[1,2]] -> [0,1,2]
```

But if there are same rows, we repeat the index, like this below, the "original" index is `k-1` for the `k`-th row

```
[[1,4],[1,2],[1,2]] -> [0,1,1]
```

Also if there is no repeat for the row (like the third row below), its index should be its original index, which is `k-1` for the `k`-th row (for example 2 for [1,4]).

```
[[1,3],[1,3],[1,4]] -> [0,0,2]
```

A longer example:

```
[[1,2],[4,3],[1,4],[1,4],[4,3],[1,2],[5,6],[7,8]] -> [0,1,2,2,1,0,6,7]
```

How to implement this on PyTorch?

Comment: I assume that by "original index" you have a pool of pairs you create a sort of dictionary from, right? In other words, how has your 3rd example knowledge that index `1` is already assigned to a pair?

Comment: Hi Ivan, there is no dictionary, the original index for the first row is 0, for the second row is 1, and third row is 2, fourth row is 3, so on. Please also see my update of the question description.

Comment: `d = {}; torch.tensor([d.setdefault(tuple(i.tolist()), e) for e, i in enumerate(t4)])`, possible but I couldn't find a vectorized solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the non-vectorized solution from @Michael

```
 d = {}; torch.tensor([d.setdefault(tuple(i.tolist()), e) for e, i in enumerate(t4)])
```

Another non-vectorized solution is

```
t4_list = t4.tolist(); torch.tensor(list(map(lambda x: t4_list.index(x), t4)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is vectorized, but relies on NumPy's `unique` function.

```py
>>> x = np.array([[1,2],[4,3],[1,4],[1,4],[4,3],[1,2],[5,6],[7,8]])
>>> _, index, inverse = np.unique(x, return_index=True, return_inverse=True, axis=0)
>>> index[inverse]
array([0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 6, 7])
```